# I want to express the product of a 2by2 matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

I want to output the result of multiplying 2 by 2 matrices.
I tried to hard-code the matrix elements and I'm not good at displaying them using loops. I have tried several times.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int m1[2][2]
    {
        {1, 2},
        {3, 4},
    };

    int m2[2][2]
    {
        {5, 6},     
        {7, 8},     
    };

    int m3[2][2] = {0};
    // int m3[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};

    // m3[0][0] = m1[0][0] * m2[0][0] + m1[0][1] * m2[1][0];
    // m3[0][1] = m1[0][0] * m2[0][1] + m1[0][1] * m2[1][1];

    // m3[1][0] = m1[1][0] * m2[0][0] + m1[1][1] * m2[1][0];
    // m3[1][1] = m1[1][0] * m2[0][1] + m1[1][1] * m2[1][1];

    int multiplyTemp1;
    int multiplyTemp2;
    for (int row = 0; row < 2; ++row)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 2; ++col)
        {
            // m3[row][row] += m1[row][col] * m2[col][row];
            m3[row][col] += m3[row][col] * m3[col][row];
            // if (row == 0 || row == 1)
            // {
            //     multiplyTemp1 += m1[row][col] * m2[col][row];
            // }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    // cout << multiplyTemp1 << " ";
    // cout << endl;

    /*
        m3 = [00, 01]
             [10, 11]
    *
    */
    for (int row = 0; row < 2; ++row)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 2; ++col)
        {
            cout << m3[row][col] << '\t';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    // for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    // {
    //     for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
    //     {
    //         // {1, 2}   {5, 6}
    //         // {3, 4}   {7, 8}
    //         m3[i][j] = m1[i][j] * m2[j][i] + m1[i][j + 1] * m2[j + 1][i];
    //         cout << m3[i][j] << "\t";
    //     }
    //     cout << endl;
    // }



    return 0;
}
```

====

I want to print to the console like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKsSa.png)
I attached an image

In this way, only the diagonal component is shown.
How can I loop to display it?
Can't display it with double for loop?
19      0
0       50

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic to mutiply and two matrix is a bit faulty. You have to use a third loop to get the correct result like this:

```
 m3[row][col] = 0; 
    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) 
        m3[row][col] += m1[row][k] *  
                     m2[k][col];
```

Following is the complete working code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int m1[2][2]
{
    {1, 2},
    {3, 4},
};

int m2[2][2]
{
    {5, 6},     
    {7, 8},     
};

int m3[2][2] = {0};

int multiplyTemp1;
int multiplyTemp2;
for (int row = 0; row < 2; ++row)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < 2; ++col)
    {
        m3[row][col] = 0; 
        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) 
            m3[row][col] += m1[row][k] *  
                         m2[k][col]; 
    }
    cout << endl;
}
for (int row = 0; row < 2; ++row)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < 2; ++col)
    {
        cout << m3[row][col] << '\t';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
 }
```